# Button handler event not firing with dynamically created buttons

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm dynamically creating buttons based on database values, this is the code that is generating the buttons.

```
test.GetSubjects();
        int subjectid = 0;

        // Current row count.
        int rowCtr;// = 0;
        // Total number of cells per row (columns).
        int cellCtr;
        // Current cell counter.
        int cellCnt;

        //count number of rows in dataset
        int rN = test.dsSubjects.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

        cellCnt = 4;


        for (rowCtr = 1; rowCtr <= rN; rowCtr++)
        {
            // Create a new row and add it to the table.
            TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
            Table1.Rows.Add(tRow);

            for (cellCtr = 1; cellCtr <= 4; cellCtr++)
            {
                //
                Button button = new Button();
                //
                HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
                // Create a new cell and add it to the row.
                TableCell tCell = new TableCell();

                button.Click += ButtonClick;
                /* If the rowcounter is equal to the record numbers
                 * then it has to break because if not it will throw an error
                 * saying that there is no row at ending position */

                if (rowCtr == rN)
                    break;

                string myStr = test.dsSubjects.Tables[0].Rows[rowCtr - 1]["SubjectName"].ToString();
                int myID = Convert.ToInt32(test.dsSubjects.Tables[0].Rows[rowCtr - 1]["SubjectID"].ToString());

                button.ID = Convert.ToString(myID);
                button.Text = myStr;
                //button.PostBackUrl = "~/WebForm2.aspx?SubjectID=" + myID;
                button.CssClass = "DynamicButtonOverlay";
                button.OnClientClick = " return ShowModalPopup()";
                tCell.Controls.Add(button);

                tCell.CssClass = "DynamicButtonOverlay";
                tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
                rowCtr++;
                /* If the cellcount is 3 then it needs to break, if not then 
                 * you'll miss every 4rth record, don't know why. But this works */

                if (cellCtr == 4)
                {
                    rowCtr = rowCtr - 1;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
```

This code works fine. As you can see in the code that its supposed to have the buttons called a handlerevent, but the handler never ever gets called. Now when the buttons are created and when one gets clicked, it is calling a javascript function to show the ajaxmodalpopup, this is the javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowModalPopup() {
        $find("mpe").show();
        return false;
    }
    function HideModalPopup() {
        $find("mpe").hide();
        return false;
    }
```

the event handler that I made is this..

```
private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        Label1.Text = "howdy";
    }
```

this handler is for testing that's why I have it looking the way it does.

I have set a breakpoint at the handler, but when I click a button its not calling the handler at all and I don't know why.
I need any of these buttons to run the event because when the modalpopup gets called, i'll be passing the buttons id (which is the id from the database) to the modalpopup which will have a form for editing the subject(button) database values and then updating the database, then after the update, I will be having the modalpopup redirect to postback the page to refresh.

So two issues are: the buttons not calling the handler and if I can get it working, then I need to get the id of the button that was called so I can populate the fields in the modalpopup.

This generating of the buttons is done on the pageload event.

Comment: Make your life a whole lot easier and don't add dynamically created buttons; instead use a `GridView` or `Repeater` and bind what data you have to it.  While this is certainly *possible*, it's *way* more work.

Comment: I have to dynamically create the buttons because I can have anywhere from 1 to 15 or more buttons. As well, I have no idea to do it the way you suggested.

Comment: Take the time to learn.  Trust me.  It'll be faster for you than trying to get this solution working, and on top of that, it's the way that you should be trying to solve this problem every other time you have it, so you might as well learn it now; you'll be re-using the techniques quite often.  There are lots of great tutorials on the subject online.

Comment: I completely understand what you are saying about learning it but I'm under time constraints and have to demo the rest of the app on Saturday. So I'm caught with either going the route you suggested or continue on with the long drawn out way.

Comment: And I'm dead serious when I say this will be faster for you.

Comment: I'm not doubting you at all and I believe what you are saying. Do you by any chance have any links to put me in the right direction? Something more narrowed down than how to use a repeater?

Comment: Google is fantastic at doing that.  Just ask it how to use an ASP repeater.

Comment: Yea I know google is our friend. No offense but this has gone off topic, either way its done its going to be the same issue in the end, my event handler is not firing from any dynamic button. My long way or your way is, and I do appreciate your input and I will be looking into it, is moot. The problem is the event handler not firing.

Comment: To be technical, the event *is* firing, but ASP is ignoring that event because it cannot find the control that fired it, since it doesn't exist, since you didn't recreate it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47461/discussion-between-user2970223-and-servy)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on when you are adding the controls, you will have to re-create the control on every postback either on the Page Init or OnLoad.

Here is one of the [best explanation](http://couldbedone.blogspot.com/2007/06/dynamically-created-controls-in-aspnet.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'm going to give it a read. Everything is done on the pageload

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was causing the issue, it was the JavaScript function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowModalPopup() {
    $find("mpe").show();
    return false;
}
function HideModalPopup() {
    $find("mpe").hide();
    return false;
}
```

For some reason, unknown to me, it wasn't allowing the eventhandler to be called. Once I removed the JavaScript, the buttons were able to call the eventhandler. Maybe it had to do with having the button calling the JavaScript function on the OnclientClick and having the buttons also calling an eventhandler. I don't know.
But it works now.